# AsyncTask Params Object parameter

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know how to handle the asynctask but i have some doubt now. Pls check my aysnctask code below

```
 public class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Log.d("Main params ", "" + params[0] );
        return null;
    }

}
```

There is no issues in code and it's running. my doubt is, when i am using different parameter in execute method i am getting result. Pls refer the code below

```
    new MyAsynTask().execute("Welcome");
    new MyAsynTask().execute(10);
    new MyAsynTask().execute(10.5f);
    new MyAsynTask().execute(11.12d);
```

here am passing different types of value but my doInBackground method have object type parameter. While am passing different values how the doInBackground gives me a result. Pls explain if anyone knows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What ever are passing as an argument, asynctask will take as object.
Letter you can convert object to any type by object  casting.

Like Int int=(Int) params[0];

Answer (score 0):

As you know object is the super class in java so in doinBackgroung after getting params[0] you should type cast after getting that value like below

```
//this is for string case
String stringValue = params[0].toString();
```

Comment: without type casting i can get all the result inside of doInBackground method. For ex : if i am passing at.execute(2) i will get the result in doInBackground . i wrote a log inside of doInBackground like this  Log.d("Main params ", "" + params[0] );  when i do this i get the result 2 in logcat. So my doubt is how the integer 2 pass and process in doInBackground ??

Comment: Yeah it you to type cast automatically when you pass in doinBackground so that why its showing 2 in printLog

Answer (score 0):

Every time you past the parameter to doInBackground compiler casts it to object type. Every primitive type int, float, bool... have object type analogue Integer, Float, Boolean... And in this case compiler will cast it to object type analogues at first, so it would be safely cast to Object type later. Object type is superclass for all object types (it is a root for class hierarchy) and it have .toString() function, but .toString is override in child classes (Integer, Float...). And according to inheritance rules child function will be called. So integer, float... will be correctly translate to strings and print in Log.